# Why is $R\text{Alg}_{J}(A,B)$ subobject of $A^B$?

Tags: category-theory

I'm reading "Standard definition" of [this page](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/smooth+topos) and have a question.

It is written that "For $A$ and $B$ any two $R$-algebra objects, let $R\text{Alg}_J(A,B)$ denote the subobject of $B^A$ consisting of morphisms $A\rightarrow B$ which are algebra homomorphisms.", where $(J, R)$ is a lined topos.

I know the definition of topos, subobject, etc ... but don't know why $R\text{Alg}_{J}(A,B)$ is a subobject of $B^A$. How do I confirm it?

**Added(edited)**

Now I may get it.

1. Assume that $a:R\rightarrow A, b:R\rightarrow B$ are $R$ algebras and I identify $b$ with $\{b\}:1\rightarrow B^R$. Let $f:B^A\rightarrow B^R$ be composition with $a$, $h\mapsto h\circ a$, $g:B^A\rightarrow B^R$ be composition $B^A \rightarrow 1 \xrightarrow{b} B^R$.
2. From the composition $(A\times A)\times B^A\xrightarrow{\times} A\times B^A\xrightarrow{\text{eval}}B$, I get $p:B^A \rightarrow B^{A\times A}$.
   From the composition $(A\times A)\times B^A\xrightarrow{\Delta} (A\times A)\times (B^A \times B^A)\rightarrow (A\times B^A)\times (A\times B^A)\xrightarrow{\text{eval}} B\times B\xrightarrow{\times} B$, I get $q:B^A \rightarrow B^{A\times A}$.
3. In a similar way for sum $+$, I gain two morphisms $s,t: B^A \rightarrow B^{A\times A}.$
4. The composition $1 \xrightarrow{1} A \rightarrow B$ defines $u:B^A \rightarrow B$ and there is a morphism $v: B^A \rightarrow 1 \xrightarrow{1} B$.
5. Now I have four pairs of morphisms $f,g:B^A\rightarrow B^R$, $p,q:B^A \rightarrow B^{A\times A}$, $s,t :B^A \rightarrow B^{A\times A}$ and $u,v:B^A\rightarrow B$.

   From them, I get two morphisms $(f, p, s, u), (g, q, t, v):B^A \rightarrow B^R\times B^{A\times A}\times B^{A\times A}\times B$. I define $R\text{Alg}_{J}(A,B)$ as these equalizer.

Is this definition correct?

Comment: I don't understand your question. $R\mathrm{Alg}_J(A,B)$ is *defined* to be a suboject of $B^A$. There is no "why" here except "that's how we define this".

Comment: I found that I don't know the rigorous definition of it. Could you tell me where it is written?

Comment: The rigorous definition of $R\mathrm{Alg}_J(A,B)$? You quoted it in your question...

Comment: I think that $A$ and $B$ are $A(1)$ and $B(1)$ of some product preserving functors $A,B:\mathbb{T} \rightarrow J$ for the algebraic theory $\mathbb{T}$, and that "R-algebra" is defined in a similar fashion. Then, how to define  the object $R\text{Alg}_J(A,B)$ in $J$ consists of R-algebra homomorphisms from $A$ to $B$?

Comment: In general, let $P$ be a property and $A$ is a object of $J$, then is there a way to define "elements of A which satisfy P" as subobject of $A$?

Comment: It won't be a subobject of $A$ but rather of the appropriate internal hom $[A, B]$. As for how to define it, you just take the equaliser of the appropriate pair of morphisms.

Comment: Yes, now you have the right definition.