# Existence of some categories in the category of categories

Tags: category-theory, foundations

I'm studying category of categories. I read that when there are categories $A,B$, it is allowed to define the product $A\times B$. Equalizers and coequalizers also exist. However, there are some categories which I don't know how to construct.

1.When one says "Let $A$ be a full subcategory of $B$ such that...", how do we define this $A$ in the category of categories?

2.How do we define "Functors from $A$ to $B$ which preserve finite limits"?

**Added**

3.I'm reading Lawvere's [Functorial Semantics of Algebraic Theories](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/5/tr5.pdf).

At the page 35, he writes

> The existence of the category $S_0$ of finite sets, the category $S_1$
> of small sets, and the category $S_2$ of large sets now follows, as
> does the existence of categories $M_0, M_1, M_2$ of monoids.

I don't understand the existence of $M_i$.

Comment: Are you looking for definitions of these, or categorical interpretation ?

Comment: First of, finite products and equalizers only exist in the category of small categories, not in the (meta-)category of all categories. Secondly, I don't see any problems with the definitions you've given. Could you elaborate where you fail and what you're looking for?

Comment: I know the set theoretic definition. In this question(http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1444983/why-is-r-textalg-ja-b-subobject-of-ab), I struggled to construct $R\text{Alg}_J(A,B)$ categorically. It's my understanding that objects must be defined in this way (using an universal property) in the category of categories. I don't know how to do this for "full subcategory" etc....

Comment: I don't see the connection to your other question. There you're constructing a very specific object of maps in a topos. The category of small categories is not a topos, and you haven't asked for any specific kind of subobject. Anyway, the only obvious kind of subobjects Cat has a classifier for is sieves.

Comment: I wanted to say that I think the condition 'full subcategory' have to be defined by a universal property.

Answer (score 1):

For the subcategory terminology only.

---

Recall that a "subset" of a set  is just another set obtained by forgetting some of its elements. Likewise,
a "subcategory" of a category is just another category obtained by forgetting some of its objects
and arrows.

In particular,

```
    subcategory of 
≡
    is a category with Obj  ⊆ Obj  and Arr  ⊆ Arr
```

and

```
    is a full subcategory of 
≡
    is a subcategory of  obtained by forgetting only some objects
```

Dully, a co-full/lluf/wide subcategory is one obtained by forgetting only some arrows.

If you want to get universal, then here:

```
  is a full subcategory of 
≡
  is a subcategory of 
 and
 for any subcategory  of  we have Obj  ⊆ Obj
```

Of course, for many, there's a "more categorical" notion.
A "subset" is just an injective function; a "substructure" is just an injective homomorphism; and generally, one considers a "subobject" as a monic arrow. So then "subcategory" is just a subobject in some ambient category of categories? For the former cases of, says, sets, fields, etc, the notion of an embedding is used for sub- but for categories there's debate. Anyhow, just some stuff to think about.